# deploy node Js app on botsolutions server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, webdeploy

I have web app project it's build by expressJs and Mongodb and I wanna to deploy it in botsolutions and are not know if can doing this or not ? [botsolutions img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0k9E.png)